# Unexpected token ILLEGAL - brunch generated app.js

Tags: node.js, templates, ember.js, brunch

I know this has been asked a million times, but I can't seem to locate the illegal characters in this line:

```
window.require.register("templates/application", Function('exports, require, module', "module.exports = Ember.TEMPLATES[module.id.replace('templates\\','')] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {\nthis.compilerInfo = [2,'>= 1.0.0-rc.3'];\nhelpers = helpers || Ember.Handlebars.helpers; data = data || {};\n  var buffer = '', hashTypes, escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;\n\n\n  hashTypes = {};\n  data.buffer.push(escapeExpression(helpers._triageMustache.call(depth0, \"outlet\", {hash:{},contexts:[depth0],types:[\"ID\"],hashTypes:hashTypes,data:data})));\n  data.buffer.push(\"\\n\");\n  return buffer;\n  \n});\n//@ sourceURL=templates/application.hbs"));
```

This line is from the app.js file generated using node/brunch from the simple empty branch of https://github.com/cbosco/ember-brunch.

I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

in Chrome when pointing to localhost:3333. Firefox gives the following error:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

It looks like it's in the generated "templates" code in app.js. The same problem happens in the cbosco todomvc project.

Steps to recreate:

1. git clone git://github.com/cbosco/ember-brunch.git ember-skeleton -b empty
2. brunch new my_app -s ./ember-skeleton
3. cd my_app
4. brunch watch -s
5. point browser to localhost:3333

Comment: Unable to repro this one... Here are the steps I took to use my skeleton:


http://cl.ly/text/311W1U3L030R

Did you make any other changes after the skeleton is created? What does your entire app.js look like?

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the reply. I think we are looking at 2 different URLs. I was trying "git clone git://github.com/cbosco/ember-brunch.git ember-skeleton -b empty"

Comment: Good catch! This is copied from README but I tried with my fork and have the same result. Try those steps (using cbosco fork) with a clean app and you still get the error?

Comment: Just tried again with a clean app and still get an error. I don't think the node version I'm running would matter, but maybe...node-v0.10.8-x64.msi. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be. Here is mine: $ node --version
v0.8.3
$ npm --version
1.1.44
$ brunch --version
1.5.3

Comment: I was @ node --version v0.10.8, npm --version 1.2.23, brunch --version 1.6.7. I downgraded them to match yours and I still get the error.

Comment: Could it be that I'm building on windows? Unfortunately, I don't have a unix box to run a test.

Comment: I guess another question could be does brunch work without specifying a skeleton for you? It may help you get an answer if the most basic brunch new my_app / brench watch -s (http://brunch.io/ "Getting Started") works or does not for you

Comment: I tired several different ember-brunch branches. This one gave me the error: "git://github.com/icholy/ember-brunch.git ember-skeleton -b empty" and this one did not: "git://github.com/vojto/ember-brunch.git ember-skeleton -b empty". So, it looks like my brunch is working.

Comment: I probably can't debug further (using OSX) but here is a tip for brunch on Windows: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/160#issuecomment-4900335